# GND connections with MP1584 DC stepdown

Tags: dc, ground, step-down

I am going to use an MP1584 stepdown to convert 9v battery to 5v to power a STM32F411CE board.
And a second one to power two 6v n20 motors.

Learned that I always have to connect GND from all components.

But the MP1584 has specific IN and OUT GND connections.

Do I "just" connect IN and OUT ground of those mp1584's ?

mp1584 : https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32824806452.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.36824c4dOvCbKN
motor : https://www.aliexpress.com/item/33016910240.html?spm=2114.13010708.0.0.3a994c4djAlU6W
STM32F411 : https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4001157813131.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.36824c4dOvCbKN

Comment: Connect where? What does the manual or datasheet of the product says to do? Can you draw a schematic diagram to understand better?

Comment: What about the link to the data sheet?

Comment: If you look at the picture of the MP1584 bottom side, you can see that IN- and OUT- is part of the same copper structure.